# A peculiar meaning

Tags: riddle

What could this mean?

```
i   n
p   w   E16
```

clue:

> Egyptian alphabet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means

> Anubis

As

> inpw is the hieroglyphic translation for Anubis, and is usually followed by the [hieroglyph E16](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Recumbent_canine_(hieroglyph)) which means ‘he who is over secrets’ (I.e. the underworld)

It looks like this:

> [image]